# How would I make my boxplot show two columns instead of one

Tags: r, boxplot

I'm trying to make a box plot that will show columns PSS_pre and PSS_post

At the moment I have the following code:

```
boxplot(PSS_post~intervention)
```

This code shows the column PSS_post, although I can change PSS_post to PSS_pre and it will show me the column for PSS_pre. How can I make it show me both colums at the same time?

Comment: Welcome Shubam,

can you tell us a little more about the data? If you combine  PSS_post and PSS_pre in a table or dataframe (PSS_combined) you can use `boxplot(PSS_combined)`

Answer (score 0):

Consider plotting a list with the 2 elements.

```
pp_list <- list(Pre = PSS_pre~intervention, post=PSS_post~intervention)
boxplot(pp_list)
```

Comment: When I try doing this, I get the following error: Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 'x' must be atomic

Anything I'm missing?

Comment: You can try with a data.frame instead of list.  Are both (pre and post) the same size?

Comment: Yes, both pre and post are the same.

I made my code into the following: 

`pp_list <- data.frame(Pre = PSS_pre~intervention, post=PSS_post~intervention)
boxplot(pp_list)`


Now I get this error: 
`Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : cannot coerce class ‘"formula"’ to a data.frame`

Comment: instead of PSS_pre~intervention , you need to pass the values. try as your case might be X[X$intervention=="SOME PRE",PSS_pre] or pre <- X %>% filter(intervention=="SOME") %>% select(PSS_pre) .... same for post in a list.